how to style lable of bottomNavigationBar to gradient color when active?
enter image description here
NavigationBarTheme(
          data: NavigationBarThemeData(
            indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
            labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.alwaysShow,
            labelTextStyle: WidgetStateProperty.all(
              const TextStyle(
                  color: AppColors.secondary,
                  fontFamily: 'Pretendard',
                  fontSize: 10,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              border:
                  Border(top: BorderSide(color: Color(0x33FDD0FF), width: 1)),
              gradient: AppColors.backgroundGradientBottomTab,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                top: Radius.circular(24),
              ),
            ),
            child: NavigationBar(
              elevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
              destinations: [
                NavigationDestination(
                  label: 'HOME',
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    selectedIndex == 0 ? AppSvgs.homeActive : AppSvgs.home,
                  ),
                ),
                NavigationDestination(
                  label: 'EVENT',
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    selectedIndex == 1 ? AppSvgs.eventActive : AppSvgs.event,
                  ),
                ),
                NavigationDestination(
                  label: 'COMMUNITY',
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    selectedIndex == 2
                        ? AppSvgs.communityActive
                        : AppSvgs.community,
                  ),
                ),
                NavigationDestination(
                  label: 'PROFILE',
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    selectedIndex == 3
                        ? AppSvgs.profileActive
                        : AppSvgs.profile,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
                log("index:$index");
                onDestinationSelected(context, index);
              },
            ),
          )),
    );



Instead of using the default BottomNavigationBar, you can create your own version using BottomAppBar and Row.
Apply a gradient using ShaderMask for the text of the active label.

For better solution please check this link
code here

If you use BottomNavigationBar and  BottomNavigationBarItem like this. It works automatically.
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    currentIndex: currentIndex,
    onTap: (index) {
      /// Switching the PageView tabs
      controller.jumpToPage(index);
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          }));
    },
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: '',
        icon: Tooltip(
            message: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.list,
            child: const Icon(Icons.list)),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: '',
        icon: Tooltip(
            message: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.tiles,
            child: const Icon(Icons.grid_4x4)),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: '',
        icon: Tooltip(
            message: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.datagrid,
            child: const Icon(Icons.dataset)),
      )
    ],
  ),
);

